# What is the minimum eligibility to see an Yaksha?

Tags: kali-yuga, yakshas

Is it possible for a human being to see Yaksha?

If yes, what is the minimum eligibility for a human being to see an Yaksha in Kaliyuga?

Comment: Why do you think people in other ages can see yakshas easily ?

Comment: Yeah, because of their strict Dharma following in other ages. It is possible for them to see easily compared to Kali yuga. IMO @RaRe

Comment: https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/8/53 and following verses give some indication about how people could see other beings..

Comment: One can talk to a Yaksha, see him if he has succeeded in Yaksha Sadhana. And, it is possible in Kali Yuga too. Are u looking for such an answer? @hanugm

Comment: @RickRoss yeah.

Answer (score 2):

There is Yaksha sadhana to obtain the siddhi, however if some yaksha is hiding among us, he can be seen using method stated in KamaRatnaTantra.

KamaRatnaTantra 12th Upadesh:

> वन्दा शाखोट चूतस्थागोक्षुरं छूवणं पदम्‌ ॥
> अजाक्षीरेण सम्पेष्य ललाटे तिलके कृते ।
> प्रकाशं जायते सर्व तच्छणुष्व समाहितः ॥

Crush and mix stem of Shakhotaka (Streblus asper), Mango tree, Gokhru (tribulus terrestris), salt in proportion of 4:1 in milk of sheep. Apply the tilak of this on the forehead. GuptaDhan (treasure) would reveal itself.

> धत्तानि यत्र वासन्तियेवा चौरादिकास्तथा ।
> गुप्तवेशा महात्मानों गन्धर्वा यक्षिणीश्वरा: ॥
> जन्तुर्द्धातुश्च वक्षाद्या मत्यंलोके स्थिता ध्रवम्‌ ।

Things that are hiding like Gandhrva, yakshini, yaksha, humans, Dhanadhik, Choradhik (theifs) will all apear if they are present there.

Comment: Interesting, have you tried anything? does it work?

Comment: @Archit Haha no, Not at all. Who would collect all those ingredients. And another thing is, tantric discriptions are often incomplete. There no info on where to do it, for how much time to do it, most preferred time to do it. Only a well experienced guru can actually tell. But it's worth trying!

Comment: Because of your answer I found something called Bhima Yaksha Sadhana in that they’ve given the where, how much time, which day starting and ingredients. But yeah guru...

Comment: I see, what I stated was titled- 'Gupta Dhana, Gupta VeSha, ChorAdi-Prakashanam'. There are thousands of sadhana, who knows? how many people really perform them! @Archit